# How do i send the results of a fomula to the audio stream in android?

Tags: android, signal-processing

I am working on something that requires some raw data to be sent to the speaker in real time on an device that runs on android.

Example 
I have a formula that generates the wave form. how do I send that data to the speaker for listening in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to write raw PCM data is via the `AudioTrack` class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack

You can operate it in a streaming mode, if needed.